# Atmega 2560 USART not giving correct value on terminal

Tags: serial-port, avr, serial-communication, atmega, usart

I am working on the serial communication of my MultiWii Pro board, which is based on a atmega2560. I am using avr-gcc to compile and avrdude to program.

Here is my problem. I am trying to get atmega2560 to send something (hex value) to the terminal. However, regardless of the value assigned to UDR2 and regardless the value I assigned to UBRR2L and UBRR2H, the terminal output is always 0xff if I set the terminal baud-rate at 9600, and 0xff if I set the terminal baud-rate at 115200.

Here is my code

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#define BAUDRATE 19200        //The baudrate to use
#define BAUD_PRESCALLER ((F_CPU / (BAUDRATE * 16UL))-1)

static void InitializeUART()
{
    UBRR2L = (uint8_t)(BAUD_PRESCALLER);                               
    UBRR2H = (uint8_t)(BAUD_PRESCALLER>>8);
    UCSR2B |= (1<<RXEN2) | (1<<TXEN2);          //RX TX  Enable
    UCSR2C |= (1<<USBS2)|(1<<UCSZ21)|(1<<UCSZ20);
}
```

And my sending function

```
void USART2Write(char data)
{
    while( !(UCSR2A & (1<<UDRE2)));

    UCSR2B &= ~(1<<TXB82); //in the case if there are more than 8 bits of data
    if(data & 0x100)
    {
        UCSR2B |= (1 << TXB82);    
    }

    UDR2 = data;
}
```

In my case, the baudrate of my code is 19200. The terminal baudrate is also 19200. No matter what I assigned to UDR2, the output will always be 0x15.

Here is my fuse setting

```
Low     High    Extended
0xFF    0xD8    0xFD
```

Comment: I assume you did check the frame format (parity, stopbit, flow control etc.) on the terminal side?

Comment: Here is my frame format on the terminal side: Baud: 19200, Data bit: 8, Flow Control: None, Parity: None, Stop Bits: One. Still, regardless of my settings of the parity bit and stop bits, the outputs were always the same.

Comment: Well this is not the framing you configured (see my answer). What happens if you leave the code and set Baud: 19200, Data bit: **9**, Flow Control: None, Parity: None, Stop Bits: **Two**?

Comment: I tried your configuration. The output value didn't change. So I changed my code to send 8 data bits instead of 9 by removing (1 << UCSZ22), and changed stop bit to 1 by removing (1<<USBS2). I used the configuration I mentioned above. It didnt seem to work out. Btw, I am using Arduino as ISP. I feed TX of Atmega2560 directly to RX pin on Arduino Uno, could this be the possible cause of the problem?

Comment: Regardless of your exact setup, you should try to keep it as simple as possible for your initial tests. How do you interface from the atmega2560 to the terminal (is this a terminal software on a PC)? It may be a problem with logic levels. Maybe you have UART TTL output on the atmega2560 side and directly interface it with RS232?

Comment: I am using the terminal downloaded in atmel studio. Basically I have my Arduino Uno connected to PC with a serial cable. This is the cable http://mchobby.be/PrestaShop/img/p/68-142-large.jpg To test the code on my atmega2560, I connected tx of atmega to Rx of the arduino uno.

Comment: The ATmega328 on the Arduino UNO only has one UART, which is interfaced with the on-board ATmega16U2 that provides the USB interface. As far as I can tell (never used Arduino), there is no spare UART to connect to. Do you have the atmega2560 on breadboard?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the Arduino Uno board itself has RX(pin0) and TX(pin1). I believe they are connected to UART of the Atmega328 on the Arduino Uno, which means these two pins are also connected to the USB interface on the board. I have the atmega2560 on another board called Multiwii Pro, which has through-hole RX2/TX2 pins onboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UCSR2C |= (1<<USBS2)|(1<<UCSZ21)|(1<<UCSZ20);
```

USBS2 sets 2 stop bits. Is this intentional?

```
void USART2Write(char data){
    while( !(UCSR2A & (1<<UDRE2)));

    UCSR2B &= ~(1<<TXB82); //in the case if there are more than 8 bits of data
    if(data & 0x100) {
        UCSR2B |= (1 << TXB82);    
    }

    UDR2 = data;
}
```

If you really want to use 9 data bits, UCSZ22, UCSZ21 and UCSZ20 have to be set. YOu only set UCSZ21 and UCSZ20

```
UCSR2C |= (1<<USBS2) | (1<<UCSZ21) | (1<<UCSZ20);
```

so I guess that USBS2 is indeed not what you want here. Maybe you were confused because the flag UCSZ22 is in the UCSR2B register.

So assuming you want 9 data bits and one stop bit use something like this:

```
static void InitializeUART() {
    UBRR2L = (uint8_t)(BAUD_PRESCALLER);                               
    UBRR2H = (uint8_t)(BAUD_PRESCALLER>>8);
    UCSR2B |= (1 << RXEN2) | (1 << TXEN2) | (1 << UCSZ22);
    UCSR2C |= (1 << UCSZ21) | (1 << UCSZ20);
}
```

Another thing: Your variable `data` is of type `char` and char is normally 8 bit wide. So the condition `if(data & 0x100)` is never satisfied.